# How long does importing bertopic usually take?

Tags: python, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

I have been trying this code and it has been running for about 24 hours and it sill running. Is this normal or should I be doing something else?

`from bertopic import BERTopic`

Device name LAPTOP-MPCB37I4

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz

Installed RAM   16.0 GB

System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Comment: This is highly dependent on a lot of factors, like your hardware and the package and your internet speed if it needs it. The only way to know it's if there was multiple benchmarks for this test case for multiple setups.